# Google Confused (Two Sites on One Server)

Tags: seo, google, googlebot, ranking, search

I have two sites / domains (https://www.pcfixes.com & https://www.flcleaner.com) on same server.

Having tweaked the nginx profiles for both sites, I believe Gbot went on PCfixes.com and was accidentally redirected to FLCleaner.com.

I'd appreciate if anyone can give insight into whether this will have bad consequences for PCfixes.com?

[image]

I'd also appreciate to know if my current nginx is okay? I've tried on 10 computers and all have the sites as totally separate entities...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue when setting up two sites from a single IP - Google appears to get confused when it attempts to resolve a site by IP only.

Add both sites to Search Console, make sure they're being indexed and have backlinks confirming their addresses. It will eventually correct itself.

Comment: Thanks - I have already added to the Search Console so will just focus on getting both up and running properly. Another thing was `https` which G seems to have successfully found

Comment: SEs are not supposed to access a website by an IP address unless there is no domain name associated with it. Google will of course, however, the preference is not to. You have likely hit the nail on the head with your suggestion of access by IP address. If that is the case, if no catch-all site is set-up, then it will hit the first site created. What concerns me is that in the SERP link is a domain name and not an IP address. For the OP, I rather feel that it is just a matter of time. Google does screw up simple things sometimes. Seriously! I know it is hard to believe. ;-) Cheers!!

Comment: Whilst the problem persists, I am sure when the sites are built (FLCleaner has several builds ready for release), G will see the difference between the two. As a precaution, I also changed PCFixes.com to be the default site, as this is the more valuable domain. Thank you both for the input!